# Passing one object to many classes using Java

Tags: java, listener

I need to pass an object from one class to many different classes.

The aim of this is to create one method that broadcasts the object to any other classes that are listening. This is so that more classes can be added and I just need to implement a listener function for that class and not edit any of the framework.

I am trying to accomplish this without the use of JMS (if it's possible!)

Comment: @Mike -> Java Message Service

Comment: @Mike: There is a thing called Google.

Comment: Har har har. Another SO Snarky response. Let's not post questions anymore. Let's just smack a Google in everyone's face.

Comment: +1 - first time I see somebody genuinely describing the behaviour of a pattern without having known that pattern before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to the rescue! Woooosh!

Let your Subject define a method for relaying that object to many listening Observers. You can then dynamically add and remove listeners.

Comment: I knew that revision was so worth it.

Comment: Brilliant! I've never heard of Observer Pattern before so I'll write a test case for it now.

Comment: Might also help to write a small, quick Spike solution to throw away. Once you understand how the pattern works, Test drive it home, solider.